# Fatal Python error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings', when connecting to jupyter kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When i try to run jupyter notebook from cmd i can't connect to a kernel since i am getting:

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

I am using python 3.8.6, pip and everything is up to date.

Operating system Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried looking up that error message using a search engine?

Comment: yep, havent found anything helpful.

Comment: Is that all the output?

Comment: Yes, i have resolved this issue by reinstalling python on my device, later i found out that the problem couse was that jupyer tried to open a notebook that i have deleted ( jupyter didn't change kernel at all )